# Can Invoke Duplicity use touch spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, spellcasting, cleric

So the Trickery Domain's first channel divinity is Invoke Duplicity, you make an illusion of yourself, and it says

> For the duration, you can cast spells as though you
>   were in the illusion's space, but you must use your own
>   senses.

Now, I'm sure this is meant to be so that you can't just move the illusion somewhere that it can see a target that has full cover from you in order to attack them with a spell, but it brings into question whether it counts the sense of touch.
Could a cleric use this as a way to heal allies with Cure Wounds up to 120 feet away? Or use Inflict Wounds on enemies in the same way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your main question: *Can Invoke Duplicity use touch spells?* **YES**

And: *Could a cleric use this as a way to heal allies with Cure Wounds up to 120 feet away? Or use Inflict Wounds on enemies in the same way?* **YES**

Invoke Duplicity (PHB p.62)

> For the duration, you can cast spells *as though you were in the illusion's space*, but you must use your own senses.

This means you literally can cast spells as if you were standing where the illusionary duplicate is, with the exception that you must be able to target the spell using your own senses.

In the case of the Cure or Inflict Wounds spells, for instance, if you can target the creature you want to heal or hurt using your own senses (you can see them, or can touch them yourself if you are blinded somehow) then yes you can cast the spell.

Comment: Just a fun thought - Is touch a sense? I believe touch is a sense, and using this definition for Invoke Duplicity might be argued that touch is a sense, and would be unable to provide 'touch' range. This is definitely over thinking it, but like I said it's a fun thought.

Comment: I thought about that, but it is only the range that is touch not any kind of targeting requirement. If the caster was numb and had no sense of touch they could still target someone they can see. However this idea was why I considered the situation when the character was blind, they could still target their victim using their sense of touch but have the duplicate deliver the spell, though I'm struggling to think of a sensible reason you would want to do this...

Comment: Now all I have to do is try to convince my DM of this. It might seem less OP when I point out that the illusion also requires concentration, so there goes any concentration spells.